# Difference Between these two queries on join and includes using merge

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So basically i'm trying things out in rails console and i found out that there are some differences when querying with joins and includes. I'm aware of the difference between them such as lazy loading using join and eager loading using includes. But below code seem to confuse me, are they any different and why doesn't merge work with includes.

```
Table1.joins(:table2).merge(Table2.where(field_of_table2: "value")

Table1.joins(:table2).where(:table2 => {field_of_table2: "value"})
```

Both seem to give me the same result.

```
Table1.includes(:table2).merge(Table2.where(field_of_table2: "value")
```

Merge doesn't seem to work with includes but,

```
Table1.includes(:table2).where(:table2 => {field_of_table2: "value")
```

works but again generates a complex sql statement.

I am new to this, Please help me understand any ill effects of using these two statements.
I'll be delighted to post the sql statement if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Merge** - Merges in the conditions from table2, if table2 is an ActiveRecord::Relation. Returns an array representing the intersection of the resulting records with table2, if table2 is an array.

**Where** - Returns a new relation, which is the result of filtering the current relation according to the conditions in the arguments.

Where is basically filter the current relation on give condition but merge returns the common rows of other relation.

For eg.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :available, where(:available => true)
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  scope :with_available_books, joins(:books).merge(Book.available)
end


Author.with_available_books
```

The above state return all the books including the available ones.

Comment: Amd what are the difference between the query containing merge and the one without merge

Comment: By the example above if you run `Author.with_available_books` , in first query it return all the books and from second it will collect the books which exists in first query and with availability. with out merge you only get book listing irrespective of availability.

Comment: you are not understanding my question. I am aware of the difference between merge and where, but why doesn't merge work with includes? Does includes load everything into memory before completing the statement?

Comment: when you use include it fire two query to get data like `Author.includes(:books).where(name: 'abc')` this results `SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" where name = 'abc' LIMIT $1 ` and second one is `SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "autor_id"."id" in (id return by first query)`. so to get books of first author you need to run `author.first.books` but when you are using joins all result is returned in one query like 'select * from authors join books on books.author_id = authors.id where authors.name = 'abc'.

Comment: And merge works with similar model records. But in case on includes we only have author record not the books.

Comment: oh, i get it now. Thanks